# Solve the following integration: $\int_{0}^{1} (x^n)* (x-a)^{\beta-1} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I integrate the following integrand ?

$$\int_{0}^{1} (x^n)* (x-a)^{\beta-1} dx$$

My step for solving it was $uv$ method. But this method is not working.

I have tried to reform the integrand as Beta form since the range is from $0$ to $1$.
but I couldn't form it.

please, show your works step by step.

it will be very helpful for me if you also integrate that integrand when the range is unknown ie, for indefinite integration.

Comment: @AWertheim Thank you very much for reforming the question.

Comment: Does that little star means multiplication or convolution (and, thus, integral within integral)?

Comment: @DonAntonio little star means multiplication

Comment: Ok @Tree, so then my answer's relevant and, hopefully, helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant the integral

$$\text I:=\int\limits_0^1x^n(x-a)^{\beta-1}dx=a^{\beta-1}\int\limits_0^1x^n\left(\frac xa-1\right)^{\beta-1}dx$$

Substitution

$$\frac xa=u\implies dx=a\,du\implies \text I=a^{n+\beta}\int\limits_0^{1/a} u^n(u-1)^{\beta-1}du=a^{n+\beta}\,B\left(\frac1a\;,\;n+1\;,\;\beta\right)$$

The rightmost factor is the [Incomplete Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html)

Comment: $$\frac xa=u\implies dx=a\,du\implies \text I=a^{n+\beta}\int\limits_0^{1/a} u^n(u-1)^{\beta-1}du=a^{n+\beta}\,B\left(\frac1a\;,\;n+1\;,\;\beta\right)$$

Comment: ??...Yes? Do you want to ask something? Is everything clear?

Comment: i am really sorry.I don't know LaTex. My question is the formula of incomplete beta function is                                     B(x; y,z) = ∫(0 to x){t^(y-1)} * {(1-t)^(z-1)} dt ; 0 <x<1
But in the given answer it has (t-1) ^(z-1) ;not (1-t)^(z-1)
Again the given a lies between -∞ to +∞. So 1/a can be negative.
So it is not also fulfilling the condition 0<(1/a)<1
kindly explain .

Comment: Well, first of all you can take out of the original parentheses $\,a\,$ or $\,-a\,$ , as it suits you. Second, as far as I can see, the imcomplete Beta Function doesn't require $\,0<\frac1a<1\,$ ...

Comment: pardon me . i took out of the original parentheses a or −a. But here comes a term (-1)^(β-1).   Again don't incomplete beta function requires the condition 0<x<1 ie; B(x; y,z) = ∫(0 to x){t^(y-1)} * {(1-t)^(z-1)} dt ; 0 <x<1